# Get True when getting any input (Python)

Tags: python, input, boolean

I'm new to programming. I searched for an answer but didn't seem to find one. Maybe I just can't Google properly.

I want to get something `True`, when the user inputs anything. Example:

```
another_number = input("Want to enter another number? ")
```

What I want:

```
if another_number = True
   float(input("Enter another number: "))
```

Sure I can say `if another_number = ("Yes", "yes", "Y", "y")` but in my program I want to get True when entering really anything.

Comment: ```if another_number:``` simply will do. Any **non-empty** string in python always evaluates to True

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Perfectly reasonable question, good for you for asking and using code formatting etc. Good luck with learning Python!

Comment: By the way, you mentioned the other option of checking a list of strings. Sometimes people do this sort of thing: `if another_number.lower() in ("yes", "y", "ok")` — casting to lowercase means you only have to check once. (Strictly speaking `str.casefold()` is the proper way though.)

Answer (score 0):

Strings that contain characters are 'truthy', so you can do something like:

```
if another_number:
    x = float(input("Enter another number: "))
```

The empty string is 'falsy', so this produces nothing:

```
s = ""
if s:
    print("s has characters")
```

This trick also works on other Python objects, like lists (empty lists are falsy), and numbers (0 is falsy). To read more about it, check out answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false).

Answer (score 0):

In python, any **non-empty** string is evaluated to True.
So, you can simply do:

```
another_number = input("Want to enter another number? ")
if another_number: #==== Which means 'if True'
   float(input("Enter another number: "))
```

And that will allow for any input.

Alternatively, you can also fo:

````
another_number = input("Want to enter another number? ")
if another_number!='': #=== if string is not blank as without entering anything, '' is returned. You can also use ```if len(another_number)!=0: where the length of the string is not 0
   float(input("Enter another number: "))
````